# Загрузка xml из архива

Tags: c#, xml, потоки-данных, zip

Использую DotNet Zip. Нужный файл помещаю в переменную ZipEntry. Потом надо его распокавать и загрузить в XmlDocument. Пробовал так:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
zipEntry.Extract(ms);
doc.Load(ms);
```

Но компилятор говорит, что нет корневого элемента. Если же сначала сохранить поток на диск и отдавать в метод Load путь к файлу, то все прекрасно загружается. Просто хочется сразу же запихать из потока в DocumentXml и дальше работать. Подскажите почему не получается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не работал с DotNet Zip, не знаю особенностей работы метода zipEntry.Extract, но, возможно, после выгрузки стоит передвинуть позицию потока на начало?

Comment: Блин! Точно! Уже который раз на этом при работе с MemoryStream попадаюсь:D Спасибо!